# Design ui controls without using code

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

I see that I can create the the UI controls like buttons, labels and textboxes by writing code in the class, and drawing them through the "pushScreen" method.

My question is: can we draw UI design by drag & drop from a toolbox?

I have been working in iPhone development, and expecting that Eclipse would have a similar approach for UI design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as what I know there is no alternate approach for UI design in blackberry except coding. The only approach for UI design in blackberry is through coding.

Comment: Unfortunately, Dinesh is right. There are no drag and drop tools to create a BlackBerry app.